# How to setup read callback for net/http GET request as I do with go-curl?

Tags: go, http, callback

We have a working golang program which fetches snapshot / image from a Dahua camera. We would like to enhance this to add read callback function for the following URI - `http://192.168.x.x/cgi-bin/eventManager.cgi?action=attach&codes=[VideoMotion]`. This URI keeps the socket open from the camera side the camera keeps sending the events through this.

We tried using [go-curl](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/andelf/go-curl) as it supports registering read callback. But, the package does not have support for MIPS architecture. Hence, we could not use it. Any suggestions / help would be beneficial. Here is the working code for snapshot fetch.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/icholy/digest"
)

const (
    username = "xxxxx"
    password = "xxxxx"
    uri = "http://192.168.x.x/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &digest.Transport{
            Username: username,
            Password: password,
        },
    }

    resp, err := client.Get(uri)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Fatalf("Error: Status code %d", resp.StatusCode)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Snapshot fetched")
    }

    // Perform next steps
}
```

Comment: What _precisely_ is "read callback function"? HTTP does not have this notion.

Comment: Did you mean to keep the connection open and keep reading the response body in a loop?

Comment: @kostix, more precisly the equivalent of the following:     // Set callback function to handle response
    easy.Setopt(curl.OPT_WRITEFUNCTION, func(ptr []byte, userdata interface{}) bool {
        // Handle the response data (ptr)
        fmt.Print(string(ptr))
        return true
    })

Comment: OK, so what's the problem with reading data from `resp.Body` and inspecting `resp` fields in place of that `// Perform next steps` comment then?

Comment: You seem to be talking about `go-curl`, but since that package appears to be a thin wrapper around `libcurl`, we could consult [the doco on `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html), and it says: «This callback function gets called by libcurl as soon as there is data received that needs to be saved.». Given that, I do not understand what problem you really have. Have you tried to read the docs on `http.Client.Get` and `http.Response.Body`? If yes, do you have any _specific_ problem with processing the data?

Comment: @kostix, It was a silly mistake from my end. I was thinking that the Get call is not coming out as the camera does not close the connection. After adding a print below the Get call, I noticed that the execution continues and I can read the response. I will paste the complete code as answer.

Comment: Glad you have sorted it out ;-) I think the question should be better closed as not reproducible but I'm fine either way.

Comment: One more note. Your answer suggests you might be still too mentally attached to the (messy) way `go-curl` handles reading response's body. Go handles blocking reads from the network _transparently,_ so you very rarely ever need explicit buffers to process such data. For instance, you could directly stream the camera's response to a file by opening a file and then doing `io.Copy(file, resp.Body)`. JSON-encoded responses can be decoded on-the-fly using `encoding/json.Decoder` and so on and so forth. Leverage this goodness!

Comment: @kostix, As posted in the answer, I am not using the go-curl. However, I would need to process the incoming data from camera in the edge device where i am running this. I may not want to write the buffer to a file as the edge device has less powerful cpu and io may lead to slowness. I will make use of json.Decoder as you suggested. I need to wait for 2 days to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my misunderstanding that the client.Get(uri) call is getting blocked. @kotix's  following comment made me to re-think about the code. After adding a print below client.Get(uri), it was confirmed that the execution continues.

> OK, so what's the problem with reading data from resp.Body and inspecting resp fields in place of that // Perform next steps comment then?

Here is the complete code that prints the events as it arrives.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "io"
    "github.com/icholy/digest"
)

const (
    username = "xxxx"
    password = "xxxx"
    uri = "http://192.168.x.xxx/cgi-bin/eventManager.cgi?action=attach&codes=[VideoMotion]"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &digest.Transport{
            Username: username,
            Password: password,
        },
    }

    resp, err := client.Get(uri)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    log.Print("Coming here");
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Fatalf("Error: Status code %d", resp.StatusCode)
    } else {
        buffer := make([]byte, 4096) // Adjust the buffer size as needed

        for {
            n, err := resp.Body.Read(buffer)
            if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            if n > 0 {
                // Process the chunk of data
                bodyString := string(buffer[:n])
                log.Print(bodyString)
            }

            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```